# Android Studio console buffer size

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a realy huge string(JSON) which I want to print(for testing) using System.out.println in Android Studio ehich however is not printing the apparently huge string and chops it off midway. How to do this ? / How to increase buffer size in android studio ?

Comment: Less convenient but works with anything: print directly into a textfile.

Answer (score 0):

try to print using android logger:

```
     Log.d("Json String", yourJsonString)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Log.d is giving the same trouble, but nice thought.